# No sound on my dell inspiron N5050

Tags: windows, audio, dell-inspiron

Sometimes, my laptop's sound works fine but for the most part it doesn't work, not the speakers or headphones. I've gone through my sound setting, seems fine. And if I have audio playing (and can't hear it).
 When I click the volume shortcut icon at the bottom of the screen, it shows it's playing but still nothing.
 How do I fix this??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Windows 7, please follow these steps:

First, try to make sure the sound isn't muted in the sound properties.

- Open command window (Win + R) and type **mmsys.cpl** then press OK.
- In the playback tab you should have one device, named "Speakers". This should be checked in green.
- Doubleclick this device and go to tab levels. Make sure nothing is muted here.